# CSS :first-child but not after text node

Tags: css

Is there a way to target the `<strong>` in the first `<div>` below, but not the second?  I want to style `<strong>` if it appears only at the very start of the line but `div strong:first-child` matches both:

```
<div><strong>Total:</strong> 12,000 and counting</div>
<div>A total of 12,000 <strong>and counting</strong></div>
```

I'd say it's impossible without modifying the markup?

Comment: In CSS, You can't select a text node. I would suggest you to add a class on `strong` that appears at start of line.

Comment: Use JavaScript for this or add a class to the element you want to modify.